# "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform" on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, ef-core-5.0

No matter what I do I get

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

I tried downgrading the Entity Framework Core packages, the Xamarin.Forms package, changing the .net standard version etc.

[image: -]

Those are the package versions I'm running right now.

This is the code that causes the error:

```
using (var context = new DbRequestsContext())
{
    var entries = from en in context.AllDbRequests select en;

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        HelperFunctions.ShowAlert(entry.Mesaj);
    }
}
```

The code being written in PCL, .NET standard 2.1. I don't have any references to the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` package in my code, the only reference is for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` which I'm using to set the connection string.

Comment: there are a LOT of existing hits on that error message - https://www.google.com/search?q=microsoft+data+sqlclient+is+not+supported+on+this+platform

Comment: Why are you going straight from your app to a SQL database? you should build and API that talks to your database and have your App talk to the API

Comment: @Jason yes and I went through literally all the answers and none worked

Comment: @Axemasta the app will be used just by a single person so I don't worry too much about that

Comment: I'm also curious to know if this is possible with a Xamarin.Forms app. I know the right solution would be to create an API to access the database, but I have an app which connect to a local SQLite db, and a client just asked me if it would be possible to connect the same app to a SQL Server instance in a local network. They don't need to access the database via internet. If that was possible, I could give them the app without nearly no code modifications, at a very small cost.